# HTML5 And Css3 - Footer Overlap - - Responsive Web Design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm currently styling a website using responsive web design technique so that it could also look decent when accessed from handheld devices. I have used Bootstrap for positioning the 
elements and some custom css for styling the nav-bar, footer, etc.
Most of the elements include the nav-bar work fine except the fact that my footer keeps overlapping the other elements when shrink the web-page vertically. Have a look at the code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

```
html
{      
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body
{
    height: 95%;
}

#body
{
    height: 82%;
}
header, footer, nav, section
{
    display: block;
}

footer
{
    width: 100%;
    list-style: inline-block;
    position: static;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

footer p
{
    padding: 0.2em;
    color: White;
}
#image
{
    padding: 0.2em;
}

.nav
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.nav ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav li
{
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav a
{
    padding: 3px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    line-height: 100%;
}
.nav a:hover
{
    border: 1px solid #acdd4a;       
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav a:active
{
    border: 1px solid #acdd4a;

    font-weight: normal;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.nav .current a
{
    border: 1px solid #acdd4a;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Below is my Markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>       
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">
                <p>
                   Title of webpage
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="span8">
            </div>
            <div id="image" class="span2">

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Help", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>      
    </nav>
    <div class="row-fluid" id="body">
        <section>
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">
                <p>@User.Identity.Name</p>
            </div>
            <div class="span5">
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <p>
                    &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>      
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

CSS:

```
  /* Sticky footer styles
  -------------------------------------------------- */

  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
  }

  /* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
  #wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
    margin: 0 auto -60px;
  }

  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  #push,
  #footer {
    height: 60px;
  }
  #footer {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }

  /* Lastly, apply responsive CSS fixes as necessary */
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    #footer {
      margin-left: -20px;
      margin-right: -20px;
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <nav class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
            <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Help", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <section>
                    @RenderBody()
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
       <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <p>@User.Identity.Name</p>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year</p>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
</body>
</html>
```

Ref: [http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer.html][Twitter Bootstrap Sticky Footer]

Comment: Thanks. But that puts the footer immediately after my contents. I need the footer at the bottom of my page. My code works fine in that terms but fails on overlapping...any suggestions please ?

Comment: Did you used above mentioned css?? It will stick the footer at the bottom of the page. Use the same html structure with proper id of elements, mainly #wrap, #push and #footer.